# How to Configure Daisy Ui modal in React Laravel

Tags: reactjs, daisyui

i have a problem to place the modal code of daisy UI in my React combined with Laravel project. please see this code

```
{/* The button to open modal */}
<label htmlFor="my-modal" className="btn">open modal</label>

{/* Put this part before </body> tag */}
<input type="checkbox" id="my-modal" className="modal-toggle" />
<div className="modal">
  <div className="modal-box">
  <h3 className="font-bold text-lg">Congratulations random Internet user!</h3>
  <p className="py-4">You've been selected for a chance to get one year of subscription to use Wikipedia for free!</p>
  <div className="modal-action">
  <label htmlFor="my-modal" className="btn">Yay!</label>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

what im trying to do i want to put my filter input on modal, in code above there is a comment `{/* Put this part before </body> tag */}` so i dont understand where to put this code.

in my app there is no `<body>` tag, its look like code bellow.

```
import React, { useEffect , useState } from 'react';
import AuthenticatedLayout from '@/Layouts/AuthenticatedLayout';
import InputLabel from '@/Components/InputLabel';
import Flash from '@/Components/Flash';
import Paginator from '@/Components/Paginator';
import NumberInput from '@/Components/NumberInput';
import DateInput from '@/Components/DateInput';
import TextInput from '@/Components/TextInput';
import SelectBoxId from '@/Components/SelectBoxId';
import PrimaryButton from '@/Components/PrimaryButton';
import { Link } from '@inertiajs/inertia-react';
import { Inertia } from '@inertiajs/inertia';
import { useForm } from '@inertiajs/inertia-react';


export default function Merchandise (props){
const { data, setData, get, processing, errors, reset } = useForm({
    name: '',
    merchandise_category_id: '',
    price: '',
    from: '',
    to: '',
    stock: ''
});

const onHandleChange = (event) => {
    setData(event.target.name, event.target.type === 'checkbox' ? 
    event.target.checked : event.target.value);

};

const submit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    get(route('merchandise.list'));
};


return (
    <AuthenticatedLayout auth={props.auth} errors={props.errors}>
    <div className="w-full lg:max-w-7xl mt-1 px-4 py-4 bg-white shadow-md overflow-hidden sm:rounded-lg">
    { props.flash.message !== null ? <Flash message = {props.flash.message}/> : <div></div>}  
    <div>      
            <form onSubmit={submit}>        
                <InputLabel forInput="Name" value="Name" />
                <TextInput
                        type="text"
                        name="name"
                        value={data.name}
                        className="m-2 input input-bordered w-full"
                        handleChange={onHandleChange} 
                />
                <InputLabel forInput="Price" value="Price" />
                <NumberInput
                        type="number"
                        name="price"
                        value={data.price}
                        className="m-2 input input-bordered w-full"
                        handleChange={onHandleChange} 
                />
                <InputLabel forInput="stock" value="Stock" />
                <NumberInput
                        type="number"
                        name="stock"
                        value={data.stock}
                        className="m-2 input input-bordered w-full"
                        handleChange={onHandleChange} 
                />
                <InputLabel forInput="From" value="From" />
                <DateInput 
                        type="date"
                        name="from"
                        value={data.from}
                        className="m-2 input input-bordered w-full"
                        handleChange={onHandleChange}

                />
                <InputLabel forInput="To" value="To" />
                <DateInput 
                        type="date"
                        name="to"
                        value={data.to}
                        className="m-2 input input-bordered w-full"
                        handleChange={onHandleChange}

                />
                <InputLabel forInput="Category" value="Category"/>
                <SelectBoxId className
                        name="merchandise_category_id"
                        value={data.merchandise_category_id}
                        data={props.merchandiseMaster}
                        handleChange={onHandleChange}
                />
                <InputLabel forInput="User" value="User"/>
                <SelectBoxId className
                        name="user_id"
                        value={data.user_id}
                        data={props.user}
                        handleChange={onHandleChange}
                />

                <PrimaryButton className="" >
                    FILTER
                </PrimaryButton>
            </form>
    </div>
    </div>

    
    </AuthenticatedLayout>
      
)
}
```

Please help me to figure it out
thankyou in advance